Error: No named parameter with the name 'clipBehavior'
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.2/lib/src/flutter/flex.dart:454:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'clipBehavior'.
clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Users\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3s

I try to  flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter pub add badges:^3.1.2  -> flutter pub add flutter_svg:'^2.0.10+1' -> flutter pub upgrade -> flutter run

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think there is an incompatibility between flutter and velocity_x-4.1.2.
You can fix this issue by modifying the package itself in the file :
C:\Users\Anis\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\velocity_x-4.1.2\lib\src\flutter\flex.dart
comment the line 454 which cause the problem in the line:
return OverflowBar(
  key: key,
  //clipBehavior: clipBehavior, //comment this line
  overflowAlignment: overflowAlignment,
  overflowDirection: overflowDirection,
  overflowSpacing: overflowSpacing,
  spacing: spacing,
  textDirection: textDirection,
  children: children,
);

do this until velocity release a new version to fix the error
